# Text diff visualization control for WinForms or WPF

Tags: .net, diff, custom-controls

In continuation of the my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diffmerge-engine-for-net), are the any good controls for text diffs visualization?

Something like StackOverflow's revision diff viewer but for WinForms or WPF

Requirements:

- free, preferably open-source
- based on WPF or WinForms

No apps please, only components.

**I'm not interested in OSS diff tools**

Answer (score 12):

There is (as part of GitSharp) an open source diff engine in c# with a very easy to use API and (as part of GitSharp.Demo) a WPF diff viewer. The code should not be too difficult to extract from the project.

Find more information here: http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp#GitSharp.Demo

Answer (score 9):

might also want to take a look at [MeneesDiffUtils](http://www.menees.com/DotNet.htm). Has a bunch of diff related utils including a visualization control. Full source code provided and is under a license called CharityWare.

Comment: There is a [WPF project](https://github.com/Dirkster99/Aehnlich) that looks at porting the implementation from Bill Menees over to WPF

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [DiffPlex](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex). It is `netstandard1.0` and very light weight.

You can easily embed it in your WPF application using the `RichTextBox` like this: https://github.com/halllo/WpfDiff

Answer (score 4):

I never heard about a specific .NET component for diff visualization (it's kind a niche), but perhaps you could rely on advanced editor to build your own without too much trouble.

Syncfusion proposes a [complete component suite](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/default.aspx) dedicated to text/code edition, with a lot of built in features that you might find useful :

- [Line and selection background](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/Advanced_Editor_Functions/Line_and_Selection_Background.aspx)
- [Text highlighting](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/Advanced_Editor_Functions/Text_Highlighting.aspx) (colored underline, waveline, borders, strike, etc.)
- [Selection margin](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/Advanced_Editor_Functions/Selection_Margin.aspx)
- [Text selection](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/Advanced_Editor_Functions/Text_Selection.aspx)
- [Syntax highlighting](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/edit/windows/features/Syntax_Highlighting_and_Code_Coloring/Syntax_Highlighting.aspx)

Important note : it is **not** free.

Comment: AvalonEdit also supports all these features - Important note: Its free