# can use javascript in window C#

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

i want to use AJAX and javascript in window platform ...can i use it in vs 05 C# window?

Comment: hy would you want to do it in a winform?

Comment: yup i want to do it in window form

Comment: But why? There are other ways to do async HTTP request from C#.

Comment: Why, why oh why?  Winforms allows on demand C# code which allows so much more than Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: jflkjdkfjkljsafkjklsf fjksjfdk

Comment: According to a comment from OP this question doesn't even related on what OP wants to do. Maybe you should rewrite it and post what you really want to achieve??

Answer (score 4):

The options I know about:

1. **JSC.exe**
   You can compile Javascript into a managed assembly, and call it as you would any .NET assembly.
2. **COM**
   You can package Javascript logic as COM, and call it from .NET, or from any COM environment.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848246/how-can-i-use-javascript-within-an-excel-macro).

**EDIT**: This allows Javascript, but not AJAX.  AJAX is a term that specifically applies to browsers, primarily using Javascript to retrieve information and potentially dynamically update the browser page without an explicit page refresh.  This generally doesn't make sense in a Windows Form app built in C#, because you have C#, and asynchrony is built in to the .NET platform.

Comment: Either one of those is a lot of work and probably more code than can be posted here.  At least the COM method is.

Comment: The COM method is not too complicated; there's a link showing how to package Javascript as COM, that link has full working source code and employs the Google Diff/Match/Patch Javascript library as an the basis for the example.  It's bona fide.

Comment: JSC is a compiler for going the other way - C# compiled into Javascript

Comment: I don't think so.  I think JSC.exe compiles Javascript into IL, just as vbc.exe compiles VB.NET into IL.  Just as I said above.

Answer (score 1):

Erm - AJAX is just the name for the techonologies and patterns used to make HTTP requests in Javascript.  Javascript itself will run in any Javascript engine; most browsers embed one, and you can also use the [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) standalone engine (though a lot of Javascript will assume a browser environment, which can get flaky).

C# is not Javascript, and to my knowledge, Visual Studio is not a Javascript interpreter.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: i want to show a text box in my form .....if user write any thing it show .....how many character you have write ...like stackoverflow add comment ....how can i do it? i may use it in validation check ......

Comment: Forget Ajax - you don't need to make an HTTP request to count characters (Stackoverflow doesn't). I suggest asking the actual question rather then an X-Y question ( http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341 ) - especially when Y won't even come close to solving X.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to your app, navigate it to whatever HTML + JS page you want, and do all the AJAX you want there.

Comment: I mean, lets not make this more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript/JScript to write code as part of a Windows Forms Application. It seems you are after asynchronous data transfer functionality (posh ;) / AJAX which will need to be implemented seperately. Alternatively, if you are looking to provide a scripting language to your users, try [IronPython](http://codeplex.com/IronPython)

For a more detailed answer, state in the question the specific part of JavaScript you would like to use, and we'll give alternatives.

**EDIT**: Oh. You can! Look at the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) javascript engine, running on [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)