# Using Javascript in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, wsc

I'm currently creating an Excel workbook that runs a Monte Carlo type simulation.  The simulator code is currently in Javascript though, and porting entirely to VBA appears to be non-trivial given the team's inexperience with this language.  So, I've been able to incorporate the javascript components into a WSC file, which works well.  (Simplified example below.)

```
    Sub Simulate()
        Set ATPSim = GetObject("script:http://www.example.com/ATPSim.wsc")
        'Set ATPSim = GetObject("script:C:\ATPSim.wsc")
        Dim ParamOne As Integer
        ParamOne = Range("B2").Value
        Dim ParamTwo As Double
        ParamTwo = Range("B3").Value
        Dim ParamThree As Double
        ParamThree = Range("B4").Value
        Range("B1").Value = ATPSim.simulate(ParamOne, ParamTwo, ParamThree)
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this requires me to host the javascript code or rely on unsophisticated users to update the absolute path.  Is there a self-contained solution?  I'd prefer to keep everything in one .xlsm file which can be e-mailed to the users.

Comment: You could store the js in a cell (if there's not too much code) and then use that to write out a file to the user's temp folder.

Comment: Like this http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/06/data-tables-monte-carlo-simulations-in-excel-a-comprehensive-guide/ ?

Comment: The temp folder idea is an interesting one that should work.  I'll have to look into it.  The final simulation code will likely be rather complex, but I doubt it'll exceed a few hundred KB.

The Chandoo tutorial uses pure excel rather than VBA or JS.  Unfortunately, this simulation has far too many branch points to model with a spreadsheet (it'd require something like 100 million cells).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to host the JS in a COM Component and use WSH to access it.

See the example here: [How can I use JavaScript within an Excel macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848246/how-can-i-use-javascript-within-an-excel-macro)

Comment: That's what I did, AFAIK (perhaps my terminology isn't correct?).  As I understand it though, this approach requires registering the WSC or keeping it in a predictable location.  I do not anticipate the end users being savvy enough to do either.