# Using Subversion TortoiseSVN Merge Algorithm in a .NET Project

Tags: .net, svn, tortoisesvn, diff, tortoisemerge

I have a whole bunch of pairs of files that have subtle differences.  We use subversion for a source control, and I like the Merge/Diff utility that comes with TortoiseSVN for windows.  And I can use this utility to manually compare/merge two files together.  My question is this:  How can I **programmatically** merge two files together the same way this utility does (and ignore and flag files that have conflicts)?

Answer (score 2):

This may help: [Automating TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using one of the .NET libraries that support an established merge algorithm, such as suggested in this question: [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net)

No idea about quality, I also stumbled across this: http://razor.occams.info/code/diff/

Comment: No success with anything mentioned on that question, and the link you included has a blatant message on it indicating that the code is buggy.

Comment: If you know your data sets, it may be simpler to hand tune something yourself. (In another comment you say that they are "mostly inserts", for example). I did run across a guy who build a diff utility and encapsulated the diff itself in a library: http://www.menees.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A few options I know about:

- [Sharp SVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) as used by the [ANKH](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) source control provider for Visual Studio. It's slow to grab repositories however
- [DotSVN](http://www.dotsvn.net/) - *'.Net port of Subversion'*
- If veering away from subversion isn't a problem, you could try Google's [Diff Match Patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).

I'm not sure if the two subversion projects implement merging, but I imagine it's a server command. The diff won't be and I'd recommend the Google one for that.

I may be way off the mark if you just want to automate tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

Merging two files where there is no conflict, without human intervention, is probably not a good idea, unless you can easily tell what the change actually is, such as having the before-version of both files (like Subversion does.)

For instance, given the following two files, what is the correct course of action? (The # column is the line number, gaps means lines are missing)

```
--- File #1 ------------------------        --- File #2 ------------------------
1   This is the first line                  1   This is the first line
2   This is the second line                 2   This is the second line
3   This is the third line
4   This is the fourth line                 3   This is the fourth line
                                            4   This is the fifth line
5   This is the sixth line                  5   This is the sixth line
```

So, what is the correct result here?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do have "before versions" just like Subversions, that's why I figured I could tap into the algorithm because it is a perfect fit.

Comment: In the example you provided, there would be a conflict on lines 3, 4, and 5, correct?  So this file would not get merged, but flagged for human intervention.

Comment: Also, I want to mention that 95% of the time, the modifications are going to be inserted lines, so conflicts should be rare.