# How to show difference for japanese, chinese and other unicode text

Tags: c#, diff

I'm looking for a way to programmatically, in C#, show the difference of two chunks of text.

The result, with deletes, adds are going to be shown in HTML, but that is a second step, and is an optional answer for the question.

I would like not to call/shell out to a command line if possible, ie calling third party diff tool or similar. Platform is Windows.

It must support Asian languages, such as Japanese, Chinese and Korean, meaning that traditional word break characters don't (necessarily) apply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net) thread. Few choices for diff engine are listed there - perhaps one of them can suite you.