# Merge two strings (text files)

Tags: c#, .net, merge, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net)

I got two text files that I would like to merge in some way. The first is just a edited version of the second.

Are there any open source tools available which can help me with that?

**Edit**: I want to find the changes between the two files and merge them as subversion does when it updates code files.

Comment: Closing my own question as a duplicate :) Will not delete it since I didn't come up with the correct keywords. Might help others if I keep it as a duplicate.

Comment: are you searching for an SVN?(sub version tool ) then try http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Comment: No, I'm searching for a diff engine to be used in my app.

Comment: http://winmerge.org/ check out this may help its open source

Answer (score 2):

See example in this arkicle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem.

Firstly you have two big files. Then you should find their longest common subsequence (LCS) and divide files to three parts:

1: Before LCS;
2: LCS;
3: After LCS.

Then you should compare independent parts "1" and parts "2" (you have a recursion).
Iteratively you decrease secuence to compare.

Total complexity will be between O(n*log(n)) and O(n*n).