# How to determine whether two word documents are the same using word interop

Tags: c#, com, office-interop

Is there a good way to see if two documents are the same using the word interop?

I have tried using something like:

```
Word.Document tempDoc = app.CompareDocuments(document1, document2);
```

My issue is that tempDoc is not null if they are the same, so I'm not sure how to use this result to determine whether the documents are the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document it returns is a document with track changes turned on. So all you have to do is see if there ARE any changes. So:

```
Document tempDoc = app.CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2);
bool anyChanges = tempDoc.Revisions.Count > 0;
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.comparedocuments.aspx

Comment: Quick question, how did you get to the _Document.Revisions.Count method from the documentation that you linked? Or did you just know about that property already?

Comment: Heh. I didn't. I looked at the properties on Document for something like "Changes", but the first method named happened to be "AcceptAllRevisions" (alphabetically), which made me think that there is probably a property named Revisions. And there was. Better to be lucky than good I always say. :)