# Compare two word document in c#

Tags: c#, devexpress-wpf, text-comparison

I have a problem. I need to compare word document. Text and format in c# and i found a third party library to view and process the document and it is Devexpress. So i downloaded the trial to check if the problem can be solved with this

Example i have two word document

1: **This** *is* a text example

2. **This** *is* not a text example

In the text above the difference is only the word **not**

My problem is how can i check the difference including the format?

So far this is my code for iterating the contents of the Document

```
public void CompareEpub(string word)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditDocumentServer srv = new DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditDocumentServer())
                {
                    srv.LoadDocument(word);
                    MyIterator visitor = new MyIterator();
                    DocumentIterator iterator = new DocumentIterator(srv.Document, true);
                    while (iterator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        iterator.Current.Accept(visitor);
                    }
                    foreach (var item in visitor.ListOfText)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("text: " + item.Text + " b: " + item.IsBold + " u: " + item.IsUnderline + " i: " + item.IsUnderline);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }


        public class MyIterator : DocumentVisitorBase
        {

            public List<Model.HtmlContent> ListOfText { get; }

            public MyIterator()
            {
                 ListOfText= new List<Model.HtmlContent>();
            }

            public override void Visit(DocumentText text)
            {
                var m = new Model.HtmlContent
                {
                    Text = text.Text,
                    IsBold = text.TextProperties.FontBold,
                    IsItalic = text.TextProperties.FontItalic,
                    IsUnderline = text.TextProperties.UnderlineWordsOnly
                };
                ListOfText.Add(m);
            }
        }
```

With the code above i can navigate to the text and its format. But how can i use this as a text compare?

If I'm going to create a two list for each document to compare.

How can i compare it?

If i'm going to compare the text in with another list. Compare it in loop.

I will be receiving it as only **two** words are equal.

Can help me with this. Or just provide an idea how i can make it work.

I didn't post in the devexpress forum because i feel that this is a problem with how i will be able to do it. And not a problem with the trial or the control i've been using. And i also found out that the control doesn't have a functionality to compare text. Like the one with Microsoft word.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Desired output

**This** *is* (not) a text example

The text inside the **()** means it is not found in the first document
The output i want is like the output of Diff Match Patch
https://github.com/pocketberserker/Diff.Match.Patch

But i can't implement the code for checking the format.

Comment: What do you want to have as outcome? Just whether they are the same, or more? Do you want to know the differences? How? In what format?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for the lack of details

Comment: Why do not you use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. It will give you the compare method OfficeWord.Document. For reference check herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244917/programmatically-comparing-word-documents

Comment: using Microsoft word. I need to have it installed in all the PC that will be using this program. So if possible i want to lessen the requirements of my application