# 3way Merge lib for .NET

Tags: .net, merge, 3-way-merge

I have no idea how I would implement a DVCS style merge in .NET. From my understanding its a 3way diff using mine, theirs and origin. I did a google search and found http://razor.occams.info/code/diff/ which appears to be a patch kind of merge (mine/original, theirs) which isn't the merge type I want. I tried doing a search with nuget and didn' find a merge there

Is there any 3 way merge libs for .NET?

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the [C# port of JS 3-way merge implementation in Synchrotron](https://gist.github.com/2633407), which is a port from the [Synchrotron project](http://homepages.kcbbs.gen.nz/tonyg/projects/synchrotron.html).

[Tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74296/tao) mentioned in in "[Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685911/6309)".