# Difference and Merging 2 Text Files

Tags: c#, text

So I have a time limited problem (the subroutine should be as fast as possible) for doing this. At any point of file I have 2 network files, like this:

```
Time: 23.369
1464953512
Bytes: 4193304
Time: 24.369
1464953502
Bytes: 4194304

Time: 24.369
1464953502
Bytes: 4194304
Time: 25.404
1464953527
Bytes: 4194304
```

Take note the 2 files are different and each contain a subset of information, and **I need to merge these 2 to create the cumulative information(removing duplicates)**, like this:

```
Time: 23.369
1464953512
Bytes: 4193304
Time: 24.369
1464953502
Bytes: 4194304
Time: 25.404
1464953527
Bytes: 4194304
```

What is the fastest way to do this? (with some code please, if possible).

Thanks.

**P.S.** I was looking at some [diff/merge libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net) but I think it will be a overkill for the same. Any simple .net/LINQ magic that can achieve it? Also, **the duplicates are serial**, **as shown and not scattered around.**

**EDIT:** -ve voters please leave a comment so that I can improve or otherwise change the question to be more suitable.

Comment: Are those numbers `1464953512` a key of some kind?  Does it belong to the Bytes/Time below or above?  If so, you can just smash objects from both files into a set and use the set to write your final file.  Alternatively, LINQ's except method is what you're looking for.

Comment: @saarrrr No the numbers are totally random timestamps from a rpc. They are useless and are just there for some legacy/other reasons maybe.

Comment: So, duplicates could be scattered around in any order?

Comment: Look at HashSet.UnionWith.

Comment: @hatchet no, duplicates are serial, as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anybody, I used this to find the union of 2 text files, having converted them into string enum before:

```
var dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\http");
var files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
IEnumerable<string> _eValA = null;
IEnumerable<string> _eValB = null;

_eValA = File.ReadLines(@"C:\http\http1.txt");
_eValB = File.ReadLines(@"C:\http2.txt");

IEnumerable<String> union = _eValA.Union(_eValB);

//TODO: create file if does not exist
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\http\union.txt", union.Cast<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read in the files, creating instances of a custom class as you go with two properties: Time and Bytes. In your custom class, override the Equals and GetHashCode methods and have them use the Time property. For example:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return Time.GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(obj other) {
    //skipping type check and null check for brevity
    return Time.Equals(other.Time);
}
```

Then just add your items to a `HashSet<YourCustomClass>`. `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicates, so you'll be good to go.